# Ruby on Rails 4 scaffolds names to match prefix

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I would like to create an scaffold in Rails 4 to match with a prefix. Should be something like:

```
rails g scaffold MMKregions
```

I mean, components should be like:

Controller file name: `mmk_regions_controller`
Controller Class name: `MMKRegions`
DB table name: `mmk_regions`

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to change command for scaffold :

```
rails g scaffold mmk_regions
```